# Merging values of 2 string arrays in one concatenated strings array

Tags: java

I have 2 string arrays.

```
string [] first = {"ajunkbc","ajunkHello","adedbc","abcjunk","add","ad","a","","junk","ajunk","aajunkbb"};
String  [] second = {"abc","aHello","adedbc","abcjunk","add","ad","a","","junk","a","aajunkbb"};
```

I'd like the result of my merge() method to concatenate each element from the `first` array with the respective element of the `second` array separated by a comma.

Below is my code

```
private static String[] merge(String [] tests, String [] expectations){

    List<String> testList = Arrays.asList(tests);
    List<String> expectationsList = Arrays.asList(expectations);

    List<String> retList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(String test : testList){
        for(String val : expectationsList){
            retList.add(test+","+val);
            break;
        }
    }
```

This does not work. What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Why do you think it should work? What do you think `for(String val : expectationsList)` does?

Comment: it loops over each element of the expectationsList. Am I approaching this problem wrong?

Comment: How exactly iteration works? What happens when you invoke `for(String val : expectationsList)`?

Comment: Hmm, I guess it just moves from one element to the next. ?

Comment: That is what happens in `for(...){here}`. I want to ask you what happens `for (here){...}`

Comment: I don't know. That's a good question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's wrong is that you are looping over `expectationsList` and breaking out of the loop after the first iteration:

```
for(String val : expectationsList){
    retList.add(test+","+val);
    break; //<--- breaking out of loop after first iteration each time
}
```

So the result is that you are always retrieving the first element of `expectationsList`.

Since what you want is to loop over two arrays, you should use an index:

```
for (int i = 0; i < testList.size(); i++) {
    retList.add(testList.get(i)+","+expectationsList.get(i));
}
```

Also, note that this implies that the size of `testList` is the same as the size of `expectationsList`. Your method should probably throw an exception if this is not the case.

Note that you do not need to convert the input arrays into lists. You can use them as-is.

```
private static String[] merge(String[] tests, String[] expectations) {
    if (tests.length != expectations.length) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("input not of same length");
    }
    String[] result = new String[tests.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < tests.length; i++) {
        result[i] = tests[i] + "," + expectations[i]);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Java 8 solution:

```
private static String[] merge(String[] tests, String[] expectations) {
    if (tests.length != expectations.length) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("input not of same length");
    }
    return IntStream.range(0, tests.length).mapToObj(i -> tests[i] + "," + expectations[i]).toArray(String[]::new);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're iterating through each member of `testList` and then for each one, iterating through each member of `expectationsList`. You want to iterate through each of both of them together.

What you want to do is something like this:

```
private static String[] merge(String[] tests, String[] expectations) {
    String[] result = new String[tests.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < tests.length; i++) {
        result[i] = tests[i] + "," + expectations[i];
    }
    return result;
}
```

This code makes the assumption that `tests` and `expectations` have the same length. You might want to do a check for that at the beginning:

```
if (tests.length != expectations.length) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("tests and expectations are of different lengths")
}
```

Notice how now you're getting the element at the same index from both arrays.

---

Sidenote: You can iterate over arrays with the for each format. This works just fine:

```
String[] myStringArray = getStringArray();
for (String myString : myStringArray) {
    // Do something
}
```

You don't need to convert to a List in order to iterate :)